# PyDev: how remove command line switch -u

Tags: python, eclipse, command-line, pydev

My code is broken by eclipse but works normaly if I launch it from command prompt with python and no option. I need to delete -u option when the python interpreter is launched in eclipse and pydev, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, so far you can't do that without grabbing the code and changing it yourself (i.e.: that's hardcoded).

But still, if you don't use the unbuffered output (i.e.: -u option), the PyDev console will end up not showing the I/O output as it's printed (as it'll be buffered).

So, what is it that breaks because -u? (maybe it'd be better fixing that then changing PyDev to launch without the -u as you may end up without the output until the run is finished if you do that).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to do this, and I agree with Fabio Zadrozny that it sounds like there is some deeper problem going on. After all, when you run in an interactive Python interpreter on the command-line, it also runs in unbuffered mode. Eclipse is just behaving more like the standard interpreter.

That said, you should be able to make sys.stdout buffered by doing the following:

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 1)
```

For stdin, just change the 'w' to 'r'. The last argument is the bufsize, where 1 specifies line-buffering, and any number greater than 1 specifies a buffer of that size (in bytes).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Adroid developers have faced the same issue...

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = '-u' ]
then
 shift
fi

exec python2.7 "$@"
```

does, indeed, strip the -u, but pydev is not happy with this arrangement on my system.
I'm new to pydev, so maybe this will help someone with more skills...
There is more, as well as Windows tips on 
[Diego Torres Milano's blog](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-android-monkeyrunner-from-eclipse.html)

Comment: Just to note from that link on the blog, the android guys did apply a patch to be conformant to the Python interpreter (so, they just remove the -u and ignore it in their case).